# 2020 Pro-Tem Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

Coffee Stack Exchange last had moderators appointed over 5 years ago. After discussing it with the current moderator team, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in October 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in October '20.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be happy to run as well. I was recently elected a mod on the Politics SE site, so I'm familiar with the tools and the needs of a (smaller) site.

I agree with Stephie that activity is low, and I don't have an easy solution to that either. Nevertheless, I'm happy to check the site on a regular basis to handle flags and the like.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider running.

I am very much aware of the fact that the user base here is quite slim and apart from a few regulars not particularly active. From what I have observed, we could do with a bit of activity, but frankly, I don’t have a magic formula up my sleeve as to how this could be solved. A slightly more involved  moderation (no offense to the current team, you were always pingable somehow) *might* be a first step. As a moderator for other sites I am around the network anyway, so to speak.

Feel free to ping me in the [Percolator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20611/the-percolator) and start a discussion!

Answer (score 3):

As one of the original pro-tem mod team, I support this. While I am happy to have been a part of this site for much of its formative time, I am no longer as active as I would like. I will continue to support and serve, but I would willingly yield to some new energy in the mod-seats!

Answer (score 2):

I might run for this if there is a short of candidates.